# Cascade dropdown JQuery - Not displaying dropdown after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

EDITED FOR CLARITY:

I have a JQuery dialog that contains two dropdown lists. It is displayed on a button click event.

I have this code in the page load event. In the code-behind I populate a couple dropdown lists with data that gets filtered. When the .commonClass fires the LoadVessels(), there is a post back.

It works perfect the first time I use it. If I close the dialog and then do the click event that does the LoadVessels(), it will post back. I don't have the dropdowns reloading from the database and I can see those values in debug console.

When I display the dialog, I see values in the ddlOperations dropdown. I can also debug and see values in the other dropdowns when it goes to the ddlOperations click event. It appears to loop through but the items on screen are not being affected.

HTML:

```
<div id="divOpSubOp" title="Select Operations/Sub-Operations" style="width:500px; display:none;">
       <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">
                  <span id="lblPier">Select Operation:</span></label>
         <div class="col-xs-5">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOperations" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">
             <span id="Span1">Select Sub-Operation:</span>
            </label>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubOperations" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control">
             </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubOperations1" style="display:none" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control">
             </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubOperations2" style="display:none"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control">
             </asp:DropDownList>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Generate" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
OnClientClick="return ValidateGenerate()" />
                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = '';
        });

$(".commanClass").click(function () {
            LoadVessels();
     });

$("#ddlOperations").change(function () {
    $("#hfOperation").val($(this).val());
    $("#ddlSubOperations").empty();
    var SubOpsIdbyVal = [];

    $("#ddlSubOperations2 > option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $("#ddlOperations").val()) {
            SubOpsIdbyVal.push($(this).text());
        }
    });

    $("#ddlSubOperations").append($("<option value='0'></option>"));
    for (i = 0; i < SubOpsIdbyVal.length; i++) {
        $("#ddlSubOperations1").val(SubOpsIdbyVal[i]);
        $("#ddlSubOperations").append($("<option value='" + SubOpsIdbyVal[i] + "'>" + $("#ddlSubOperations1 option:selected").text() + "</option>"));
    }
});
}

function LoadVessels() {
        if ($('#divShiftGroup input:radio:checked').val() != undefined && 
 $('#divPortGroup input:radio:checked').val() != undefined
          && $("#txtDate").val() != "" && 
 ($("input:radio[name='YardVessel']").is(":checked"))) {
            __doPostBack("<%=upInner.UniqueID %>", 'LoadVoyageDDL');
    }
</script>
```

The initial population of the dropdown lists are done in the code behind in VB.net

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlOperations.DataSource = "CALL TO SQL"
        ddlOperations.DataTextField = "Descr"
        ddlOperations.DataValueField = "OpsId"
        ddlOperations.DataBind()
        ddlOperations.Items.Insert(0, "")

        ddlSubOperations1.DataSource = "CALL TO SQL"
        ddlSubOperations1.DataTextField = "Descr"
        ddlSubOperations1.DataValueField = "SubOpsId"
        ddlSubOperations1.DataBind()

        ddlSubOperations2.DataSource = "CALL TO SQL"
        ddlSubOperations2.DataTextField = "SubOpsId"
        ddlSubOperations2.DataValueField = "OpsId"
        ddlSubOperations2.DataBind()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your filtration to persist across pages either your backend needs to generate a filtered list or something on the client side code needs to be executed on page load.

It is initially applied when the change event is fired on your ddlOperations. However, after a postback and your page reloads the code will not be executed until a change event is once again fired on ddl operations change.  Try moving your filtration code into a function and executing it on page load if there is a ddl operation selected, in addition to registering it to the on change event.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can see the values in the list when I fire the change even after the postback. It's just the values on screen are not changing like the initial.

Comment: It seems like you have not given enough information here. To better help you should attempt to post the code that renders your dropdowns.  Keep in mind a postback means you are executing all your javascript twice.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to posting here. I have edited and hope it is more clear. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being there was an open JQuery dialog window that was not being removed. So each time it was being opened twice but the dropdown was hidden in the DOM already and wasn't being displayed.